# Error: The manifest (with format version 2) must not contain the following tags: run_depend

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On ROS indigo, I followed the [actionlib instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) to create a simple actionclient and actionserver. I was careful to click "indigo" so I'm not accidentally following the instructions for the wrong distribution. When I run `catkin_make`, I get an error message:

```
Error(s) in package '/home/eharvey/catkin_ws/src/poi_scan/package.xml':
Error(s):
- The manifest (with format version 2) must not contain the following tags: run_depend
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there an error in the docs?

Here are the complete steps to reproduce:

```
cd ~catkin_ws/src
catkin_create_pkg poi_scan std_msgs rospy roscpp
cd poi_scan
vi package.xml
mkdir action
vi action/DoDishes.action
vi CMakeLists.txt
mkdir scripts
vi scripts/simple_action_client.py
vi scripts/simple_action_server.py
chmod +x scripts/*
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

Here are the contents of `package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>poi_scan</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The poi_scan package</description>
  <maintainer email="edward.harvey@todo.todo">turtlebot</maintainer>
  <license>GPLv3</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib_msgs</run_depend>
  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

I can share the contents of the other files too, if needed, but `catkin_make` seems to be choking on `package.xml`

I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309913/ros-python-error-the-manifest-with-format-version-2-must-not-contain-the-foll) on stackoverflow, where the accepted answer is to omit the format. Unfortunately, when I omit the format, the problem gets worse:

```
Error(s) in package '/home/eharvey/catkin_ws/src/poi_scan/package.xml':
Error(s):
- The manifest (with format version 1) must not contain the following tags: build_export_depend, exec_depend
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292888/error:-the-manifest-(with-format-version-2)-must-not-contain-the-following-tags:-run_depend/) by [rahvee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35098/rahvee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is that the actionlib tutorial has not been updated since `catkin_create_pkg` has been updated (and now generates package.xml format 2).

Can you try to replace the 2 `run_depend` with `exec_depend` ?

Edit: tutorial has been updated: http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/actionlib?action=diff&rev2=197&rev1=196

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rahvee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35098/rahvee/) on 2018-06-01**:
Thank you!  :-D

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2019-06-06**:
As an FYI, I ran into this problem when working through the [custom global planner plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) tutorial, so that page may need to be updated as well?